# how to pass textbox values through an anchor tag to a model popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to create popup menus as per the value got from the anchor tag .i don't know how to pass the values through the anchor tag.am a newbie in MVC.

*this is what i have tried to pass values*

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go", "null", "null", null, new {data_toggle="modal",data_target="#myModal4", onclick = "this.href += '&myRouteValueName=' + document.getElementById('val').value;" })
```

Answer (score 0):

In @Html.ActionLink "Go" is your link text. Your second parameter should be name of your action method and third parameter should be controller name. which in your case is null. third null is not required and in order to pass value to controller, you can do something like this:  new { id = "valueToPass" }. So, it should be something like this:

In your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("GO", "ActionMethodName", "ControllerName", new { id = "loginLink" });
```

In controller:

```
public class ControllerNameController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ActionMethodName(int id)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```